# c++ Push_back type with multiple

Tags: c++, vector, types, push-back

I have the following C++ Code...

```
struct myType
{
    int SID;
    int IID;
    std::string myString;
};

std::vector<myType[2]> _type;
```

The problem is when i do this...

```
for (int x = 1; x < 82432; x++)
{
    _type.push_back(myType());
}
```

it give me the following error

```
Error   441 error C2664: 'void std::vector<myType [2],std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const myType (&)[2])' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'myType' to 'myType (&&)[2]'
```

The idea was to create a vector array like so: _type[82431][2].SID <<= type

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create vector of array type, one of the reason is that you cannot assign one array to other, the closes you can get is:

```
std::vector<std::array<myType, 2>> _type;
```

This is also not right

```
for (int x = 1; x < 82432; x++)
{
    _type.push_back(myType());
}
```

even if you could create vector of arrays, in your loop you are pushing data of type `myType` while your vector is of type `myType[2]`. So to make it work with `std::array` change to `_type.push_back({myType(), myType()});`

see here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b77015b21524de77 for some other uses

Comment: with this, i am still not able to create an array with 2 dimension...
What i wanted was to inserted another 2 with the same type.

Comment: Arrays aren't even [`Erasable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable).

Answer (score -2):

For some stupid reason... i can just do this!

```
myType _type[82432][2];
```

Comment: If i knew this sooner, i would not have use vector... lol, since all i need is a simple array access... i wonder if there is a way to do this with std::vector?

Comment: In C++ it's better practice to use `std::vector` or `std::array`. If the two dimensions of your array are going to be constant, you can use `std::array<std::array<myType, 2>, 82432>`, or a vector of arrays like in Marcin's answer

Comment: I know it is better to use vector, but all i get is a bald head... if you have a way for vector to look like the answer above, please post it please! Actually, Thank you! to think it can work like that...

Comment: What's wrong with the answer above? It provides a way to declare and to fill a vector so that you get an equivalent for `myType _type[82432][2];`

Comment: Okay, sorry for my misunderstranding. Consider accepting Marcin's answer if it solved your problem then :)